# Why am I getting rsExecutionNotFound in SSRS integrated mode?

Tags: reporting-services, integrated-mode

I'm currently setting up a SharePoint Foundation Farm with a front-end server hosting central administration (which we'll refer to as spfrontend) and a Sql Server with SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode (which we'll refer to as ssrsserver). I can run SSRS reports uploaded to my SharePoint Site by navigating to the report through http://ssrsserver/ReportServer interface, and the reports render as expected. However, when I try to access it though the http://spfrontend/MySite interface, regardless of accessing it as a webpart on a webpart page, or clicking on the link directly, it always returns an error similar to the following:

> Execution 'mofg0y450k5icx55iz1z31bj' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)

Neither of the application logs on the ssrsserver or the spfrontend machines are reporting any special errors. How can I get the spfrontend server to correctly display my reports?

Comment: Does this mean we cannot use Sharepoint 2010 Foundation with SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @Talha If I remember correctly, I was able to install and use SharePoint Foundation on SQL Server 2008 - only the Reporting Services functionality was unavailable to me. Attempts to integrate generated the above error. Software requirements for SharePoint 2010 alone are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section137), requirements for SSRS Integration are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283190%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#sectionToggle2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint Foundation and Server 2010 require SQL Server 2008 R2 (Version 10.50). SQL Server 2008 (Version 10.00) itself will allow you to go through all the integration steps, but rendering a report on the site will yield the described error.